# GET Request not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull a string from my URL in WordPress, and create a function around it in the functions file.

The URL is:

"https://made-up-domain.com/?page_id=2/?variables=78685,66752"

My PHP is:

```
$string = $_GET("variables");
echo $string;
```

So I'm trying to return "78685,66752". Nothing happens. Is the first question mark a problem? Or what am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: `$_GET` is an array - data is accessed as `$_GET['variables']`. The first question mark is also a problem, replace the second question mark with an ampersand (&)

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` should be in the form

```
$string = $_GET["variables"];
```

and not

```
$string = $_GET("variables");
```

Comment: Sorry - that was a transcription error. Good point, but not the actual problem in this case!

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is not a function but an Array so correct way of reading it is

`$string = $_GET['variables'];`

You are also creating the query string all wrong, you should be using

```
?variables=123,456&page=1
```

Read more about $_GET here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

Your `URL` should be like:

```
https://made-up-domain.com/?page_id=2&variables=78685,66752
```

instead of:

```
https://made-up-domain.com/?page_id=2/?variables=78685,66752
```

`&` char is separating the queries in URL.

And you have syntax error. Use `$string = $_GET["variables"];` because $_GET is a superglobal array, not a function.

Use `$variables = explode(",", $string);` separate values into an array if you want. Simplier way is `$variables = explode(",", $_GET["variables"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You should format your href and get parameter like this

```
http://example.com/mypage.html?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

+ Edit your get method syntax

```
$string = $_GET['variables'];
```